# ubuntu: group chrome windows according to the profile used

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu

I use ubuntu unity and chrome with multiple profiles. I also created desktop launchers for different profiles by (named `chrome-xxx.desktop`, where `xxx` is the profile name)

1. specifying the command to use different profile like `google-chrome --profile-directory=xxx`
2. change the `StartupWMClass` to `chrome-xxx`
3. set different icon

However, all the windows opened for different profiles are all grouped into the same window group in `unity`. I used `xprop WMCLASS` to check the window class for all these windows and they are all

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "google-chrome", "Google-chrome"
```

I also searched and found that `chromium` has an `--class` option that can be used to set the window class, however `chrome` seems not to have it.

Is there any way to have the windows for the same profile to be grouped together? In `Windows OS` a simple `create desktop icon` for each profile solves the problem.

BTW, where can I find the list of cmdline options supported by `chrome` (NOT `chromium`!)?